# uploading files from client side using jquery ajax using .net

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have a requirement of uploading files from client side using jquery ajax function to different server location instead of sending it to my application web server, this is to avoid anonymous/virus upload to application webserver.

I have searched many sites, but all samples are done in php not in .net 2.0.

Much appreciate if any of you could give me a lead or solution for the same.

Many Thanks
Ananda

Comment: When I enter the exact words from your question's title into Google, I find a lot of good hits

Comment: @sandradev: Even I too found the same from google, but all the examples were given in php not in .net.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to do this uploading against a webservice. Example using WCF and stream the file to the server.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx

There are also possible using SOAP messages with attachments:
http://www.w3.org/TR/SOAP-attachments